# Recaptcha not compatible with IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, recaptcha

I'm trying to build a website working with IE9 and I must use a captcha to prevent scraping. The [official recaptcha documentation](https://support.google.com/recaptcha#6223828) is telling it should work with IE 10/9/8.
When I try to load the recaptcha v2 with browserstack, I get the following message :

```
Please upgrade to a supported browser to get a reCAPTCHA challenge
```

If I try to load [recaptcha's demo](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo) with Brave using IE9's useragent, I'm getting the same message, that's why I assume google is blocking recaptcha based on the useragent, but why is the documentation saying how to make it work on IE ?

Any informations on this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the IE browser Compatibility View settings, and remove the `google.com` from Websites you've added to Compatibility View. More details steps, check [this article](https://support.google.com/recaptcha#6223828).

Besides, you could refer to [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/ie9-is-not-capturing-recaptcha-form-fields/6479d1f0-6f67-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5) and try to add below meta tag in the header part

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >`.

If still not working, perhaps the Recaptcha you are using not support IE9 version, you could try to update your computer to the latest Windows. See [Microsoft’s instructions for getting Window’s updates](http://www.update.microsoft.com/windowsupdate/v6/thanks.aspx?ln=en&&thankspage=5).

Comment: None of this is working. I am using BrowserStack to test IE9 compatibility, they are using IE 9 version 9.0.8112.16421 Updates 9.0.46 KB3124275

Comment: I also check the [google recaptcha demo](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo) using IE 9, it will show"
Could not connect to the reCAPTCHA service.
Please check your internet connection and reload to get a reCAPTCHA challenge.
" error, but if I use IE 11 browser, everything works well. it seems that the recaptcha not support IE9 browser, please try to upgrade the IE browser to the latest version or contact the recaptcha team and post your question to [recaptcha forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/recaptcha).